# Silverlight design pattern for performance - very rich client UI

Tags: silverlight, performance, architecture

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531401/converting-an-mvp-asp-net-app-to-silverlight-3-help-me-choose-an-architecture) initial investigations on Silverlight architectures, I have some new requirements to consider.

We expect our Silverlight client UI to be graphically heavy, with a GIS interface, multiple charts, gauges and datagrids arranged in a Widget style fashion. New widgets will be dynamically generated by the user.

Suppose a user wanted to dynamically create a chart widget from an existing datagrid widget pre-populated with data. It appears to me that if we were using a MVVM pattern with the view model on the server, this would result in an unnecessary call back home when the required data is already located in the client.

Now obviously the server needs to know about this new chart widget on the client, but how do I create the widget in the client first (with the existing client side data) and then notify the server about the new changes?

In our intranet, the network link between the client and the server is not particularly good so performance is critical.

It seems from my initial research that the common Silverlight architecture patterns call for as much of the business logic to be pushed back to the server. I understand the reasoning for this, but fear that it will really hurt the usability of our application.

Are there particular design patterns that address this issue? Is this 'client-binding' supported within MVVM, Prism or other common Silverlight architectures?

Is there a more formal name for what I am attempting to describe?

I am quite new to both Silverlight and design patterns such as MVVM, so please correct me if any of my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you need a few case studies. One point I have is that "common Silverlight architecture patterns call for as much of the business logic to be pushed back to the server" is not correct and defeats the extra capabilities you have with Silverlight. You can use more powerful validation logic on the client to save the roundtrips that you'd typically have with AJAX.

Comment: @sipwiz: Indeed, I am glad to be wrong about that. I am confused about how best to define the model on both the client and server side. Some case studies would be most welcome.

Comment: What I have found is that Silverlight lets you do the same things on the server or on the client. It lets you choose which you prefer. For example, validation can be done on the server or on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVVM pattern is for separation of concerns.  It does not define how or where you get your data.

The model, is data.  It can be data you get from any arbitrary source.  In silverlight, the most common way to get data is via a webservice (SOAP/REST).  But your model can be any data from anywhere.

The view model is just another class that probably implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (So you bindings can automatically be updated).  This class is an abstraction for your view's data.  Let's pretend it has a string property called "FirstName".

The view is your UI (A user control in SL).  You setup your bindings here to your ViewModel.  IE, .

The view and view model are put together when you set your views DataContext.  myView.DataContext = new MyViewModel();  There are many ways to set the DataContext depending how you want to set things up.

Prism is just a framework to help write decoupled applications in WPF/SL.  It does not enforce the usage of any UI pattern (ie, MVP/MVC/MVVM).  What it does come with is a bunch of classes can be used to assist with MVVM development, such as a mediator (EventAgggregator) and a dependency injection container (Unity).

So enough digressing...What I would suggest, is you have a web service where you can get all your data.  You SL app would get that data (most likey the web services will be called in the view model).  That data now exists on the client side and you can setup your VM to bind to this data in your view.